# How can I run a session with user access levels within a function?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make a system of access levels for the user after making the login and soon a session is established?

I need to do with this code~

```
// Login logic
function process_login($user, $pass, AuthMeController $controller) {
    if ($controller->checkPassword($user, $pass)) {

        printf('<h1>Hello, %s!</h1>', htmlspecialchars($user));
        echo 'Successful login. Nice to have you back!';
        
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['UserSession'] = array($user['default'], $user['GM']);
    
        
        //header('Location: https://mysite');
        
        echo "<br /><a href='../index.php'>Back to Form</a>";
        
        return true;
    } else {
        echo '<h1>Error</h1> Invalid username or password.';
        header('Refresh: 5; URL=https://mysite');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: For a very small site it's not a problem to re-invent the wheel. Otherwise, you're better off using existent frameworks or database authorization.

Comment: the hash is BCrypt and I would like to know how to do what I am looking for in this function

Comment: I write access level code all the time. After the user is authenticated I pull their access codes from a database table. For example, I have a table called Permissions with rows of userId, canAddUser, canDeleteUser. The values of canAddUser and CanDeleteUser are 0 for no or 1 for yes. I then set session variables $_SESSION["canAddUser"]=1 etc. Moving forward I reference those variables to determine what actions or pages a user can visit. You don't need a special framework. There is less coding involved when avoiding frameworks. You can have a permissions table with columns Level1, Level2 etc